# React useState() issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a problem with using function component. I'm writing Hangman game and i stuck while trying to do staff about letters discovering. Here is my code.

App.js

```
import CreateSubject from './components/CreateSubject'
import Hangman from './components/Hangman'
import { HangmanProvider } from './context/HangmanContext'

function App() {
  return (
    <HangmanProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <CreateSubject/>
        <Hangman/>
      </div>
    </HangmanProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CreateSubject.js

```
import {HangmanContext } from '../context/HangmanContext'

function CreateSubject(props){
    
    const {password,displayGame,displayForm} = useContext(HangmanContext)
    const [subject,setSubject] = password
    const [gameDisplay,setGameDisplay] = displayGame
    const [createSubjectDisplay,setCreateSubjectDisplay] = displayForm
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        if(subject != ''){
            setCreateSubjectDisplay('none')
            setGameDisplay('')
        }
    }
    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setSubject(e.target.value)
        e.target.value = subject
    }
    return(
        <form style={{display: createSubjectDisplay}} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                <div>Enter a Word:</div>
                <input type='text'
                 value={subject}
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 className='createSubject'
                 maxLength='40'/>
            </label>
            <button type='submit'>Create</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default CreateSubject
```

Hangman.js

```
import al from '../alphabet'
import {HangmanContext} from '../context/HangmanContext'

const Hangman = (props) =>{
    const {password,displayGame,displayForm} = useContext(HangmanContext)

    const [subject,setSubject] = password
    const [gameDisplay,setGameDisplay] = displayGame
    const [createSubjectDisplay,setCreateSubjectDisplay] = displayForm
    
    let passwordArr = Array.from(subject)
    const [hiddenPassword,changeHiddenPassword] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        let passwordArr = Array.from(subject)
        changeHiddenPassword(passwordArr.map(item => '_')) 
    },[]);

    const chooseLetter = (e) => {
        let letter = e.target.innerHTML
        passwordArr.forEach((e,i) => {
            if (e == letter){
              console.log(hiddenPassword)
            }
        })
    }

    const letters = al.map((letter) =>
        <span onClick={chooseLetter}>{letter}</span>
    )

    return(
        <div style={{display:gameDisplay}}>
            <div className='password'>
                {
                //passwordArr.map((item,i) => <span>{hiddenPasswordArr[i]}</span>)
                }
            </div>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <div className='pass_input'>Enter password:<input type='text' maxLength='30'/></div>
                <div className='alphabet'> {letters} </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hangman
```

My problem is in Hangman.js when i'm trying to change 'hiddenPassword' state which is an array. When i'm outputing this state in console it shows me an empty array. What have i done wrong ?

Comment: Check whether your  ```passwordArr```  is empty?

Comment: Try doing this one, Instead of this " const [subject,setSubject] = password" try using " const [subject,setSubject] = useState(password)"  and import useState from React, Let me know if this worked or you are still facing issues

Comment: ```displayForm``` is ```useState(...)```?

Comment: I'm using contextApi and password is destructurized(idk if i spelt this right) object from my contex. I need to have that beacouse im taking subject as a state from another compontent (CreateSubject)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `hiddenPassword` state:

`const [hiddenPassword,changeHiddenPassword] = useState(passwordArr.map(item => '_'))`

Answer (score 0):

`subject` might have to be in the `useEffect`'s dependency array

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        let passwordArr = Array.from(subject)
        changeHiddenPassword(passwordArr.map(item => '_')) 
    },[subject]);
```

Comment: Well now it works but hiddenPassword fills up from index[1] instead of index[0]. When my password should be 'example' it is 'xample'

Comment: Okay nevermind i got it to work. Thanks for advice it helped me a lot.